# refresh sub page on reloading main page react native

Tags: react-native

I trying to reload sub-page in react native app. actually i am importing my sub pages from components. like this:

```
import {Input,Button, Logo, Topcart,Heading, BackgroundWrapper,Navigation, AlertStatus,Header,Footer} from '../components';
```

Topcart page showing count of products. all products are set in cookies on clicking add to cart button. when i click on add to cart button than new items set into the cookies and page set to the cart page Actions.cart({data:responseText}) but on cart page cart count is not updating. when i click my mobile back button to go back on previous page and again add to cart than its showing previous count. how can i refresh my sub-page . Topcart page is like this:-

```
fetchData(){ 
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userid', (err, result) => {
      if(result){ 
         cookie.getAll().then(function(cookies){                     
             fetch('https://www.furnitureinfashion.net/app_cookies_count.php?customerId='+result, {
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 },                 
                     body: JSON.stringify(cookies)
              }).then((response) => response.text())
              .then((responseJson) => {                                         
                                cartCount = responseJson;

              })
             .catch((error) => {
                 console.error(error);
              });

            });
        }
        else{
cookie.getAll().then(function(cookies){                  
             fetch('https://www.furnitureinfashion.net/app_cookies_count.php', {
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 },                 
                     body: JSON.stringify(cookies)
              }).then((response) => response.text())
              .then((responseJson) => {                                         
                                cartCount = responseJson;

              })
             .catch((error) => {
                 console.error(error);
              });

            });



            }
    })        
    }

  componentWillMount(){    
        this.fetchData();
    }
```

on cart page import  like this:
import {Input,Button, Logo, Topcart,Heading, BackgroundWrapper,Navigation, AlertStatus,Header,Footer} from '../components';

```
render() {
return(
<View>                
 <Topcart/>         
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, TopCart is only setting the count when it loads, and not updating when new values are added.

If you want to have TopCart update then you need a way to do that. You might want to look at using state. This means there would be a piece of state that is responsible for holding cartCount. Then when the count is updated, because TopCart is watching it, once it changes TopCart will re-render.

I'm not sure what you are doing with cartCount right now. Is it available to be passed down to TopCart as props? You can do the following:

```
<Topcart cartCount={cartCount} />
```

Then in the TopCart component you can reference `this.props.cartCount`. As this is now a piece of state in TopCart, changing it will cause TopCart to re-render.

The other alternative, which would be better, is to have application state using redux. TopCart would implement redux `connect()()` functionality and watch a piece of state.

I may need more info to help further.